# Can't find RemoteApp image after creating on Azure

Tags: azure, remoteapp

I've created a RemoteApp image in Azure, and run sysprep (which shutdown my VM as it is supposed to).  However, how do I get to the image now?  I assume it is somewhere on Azure, but where?

Answer (score 1):

Keith,
It is in the "images" tab.  Check out this article that has step by step = https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/remoteapp-image-on-azurevm/

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  There seems to be confusion about VM Images (Classic).  I created my VM in the new portal, but in that same portal, when I go to the VM Images (Classic) tab there are no images listed.  If I choose the RemoteApp Resource, it takes me to the Classic portal.

Comment: Eric, I've followed those steps exactly, but can't find the image.  Does it matter if I create the VM in the New or Classic portal?